# Webscraping website with HTMLSession and bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the information "The name is already registered" from the website https://app.ens.domains/name/2354.eth/register. In the first step I tried to scrape the whole website:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://app.ens.domains/name/2354.eth/register'

this_session = HTMLSession()
response = this_session.get(url)
response.html.render()

print(response.html.raw_html)
print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.raw_html, "html.parser")
names = soup.findAll("div")
```

But the output contain no information I can use to specify my search:

```py
b'<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png"><link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest"><link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5"><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797"><meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Overpass:100,200,300,400,600,700,800,900|Overpass+Mono:300,400" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="ENS App" href="/opensearch.xml"><title>ENS App</title><script async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script src="https://www.googleoptimize.com/optimize.js?id=OPT-KTCR9V9"></script><script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.64b76e39-3ba85.js"></script><style data-emotion="css"></style><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/TestRegistrar.987088ac-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/729.362306d1-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/Home.ea8fd0b4-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/171.a237641d-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/804.45936964-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/926.ce58711c-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/973.eb3a3ec8-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/333.55449608-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/SearchResults.8083ff69-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/787.796394e1-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/944.b11bdaf9-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/146.efe6852e-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/10.82d34550-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/877.ef102d75-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/409.51df15df-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/535.b54d1b5b-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/554.72170ba5-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/SingleName.9d36bc40-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/825.31eb5e1d-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/Favourites.5a13335b-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/Faq.4e16b951-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/Address.b6964377-3ba85.chunk.js"><link rel="prefetch" as="script" href="/static/js/Renew.2f93065c-3ba85.chunk.js"><style data-emotion="css"></style><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-787" src="/static/js/787.796394e1-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-171" src="/static/js/171.a237641d-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-944" src="/static/js/944.b11bdaf9-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-146" src="/static/js/146.efe6852e-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-10" src="/static/js/10.82d34550-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-877" src="/static/js/877.ef102d75-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-409" src="/static/js/409.51df15df-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-729" src="/static/js/729.362306d1-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-926" src="/static/js/926.ce58711c-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-535" src="/static/js/535.b54d1b5b-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-554" src="/static/js/554.72170ba5-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-333" src="/static/js/333.55449608-3ba85.chunk.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/SingleName.6f4b1931.chunk.css"><script charset="utf-8" data-webpack="ens-app:chunk-61" src="/static/js/SingleName.9d36bc40-3ba85.chunk.js"></script></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><script src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/6.13.2/bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fcgCrdIqrZ6d6fA8EfCAfdjgN9wXDp0EOkueSo3bKyI3WM4tQCE0pOA/kJoqHYoI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>Sentry.init({dsn:"https://7b24dc49f7014d56a422c24e18212ef3@o1010257.ingest.sentry.io/5974691"})</script><div id="root"><div class="css-lfsk6e e1506hml0" style="display: none !important;"><main class="css-pwvrwp e1iaa33a0"></main></div><div class="css-42k21n e1bb2sm1"><div class="lds-css css-197eqvq e1bb2sm0"><div class="lds-dual-ring"><div></div></div></div></div></div><div id="modal-root"></div><script defer="" src="https://static.cloudflareinsights.com/beacon.min.js/v652eace1692a40cfa3763df669d7439c1639079717194" integrity="sha512-Gi7xpJR8tSkrpF7aordPZQlW2DLtzUlZcumS8dMQjwDHEnw9I7ZLyiOj/6tZStRBGtGgN6ceN6cMH8z7etPGlw==" data-cf-beacon="{&quot;rayId&quot;:&quot;73e5d7a6cf3144f2&quot;,&quot;token&quot;:&quot;323ef669b85e40d4ba13d48f5ff255dd&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;2022.8.0&quot;,&quot;si&quot;:100}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>\n</body></html>'
```

Do I have a completely wrong approach or is it some detail I am overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it well, but the problem is that the page loads slow, so you need to wait more after the initial render (see [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#requests_html.HTML.render)). 10 seconds should be enough.

```py
response.html.render(sleep=10)
```

After this, the required div should be easy to find:

```py
div = soup.select_one("div.css-1qv42d6")
print(div.next)
```

So the full code will be the following:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://app.ens.domains/name/2354.eth/register'

this_session = HTMLSession()
response = this_session.get(url)
response.html.render(sleep=10)

print(response.html.raw_html)
print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.raw_html, "html.parser")
div = soup.select_one("div.css-1qv42d6")
print(div.next)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. the sleep time seems to work. i tried now:

`from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://app.ens.domains/name/2354.eth/register'

this_session = HTMLSession()
response = this_session.get(url)
response.html.render(sleep=10)


div = soup.select_one("div.css-1qv42d6")
print(div.next)`

But now he gives me a "NameError: name 'soup' is not defined" Error.

I tried to heal it with:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(this_session, "html.parser")`

But it doesnt work.

Comment: The rest of your code was fine, I've added the full result in my answer.